# Facing issue while retrieving transactions from Yodlee system.

Tags: yodlee

I have implemented one application to automatically get transactions back for all my customers' accounts from Yodlee at 3 AM  EST every day. It kept working for more than 7 months. But it failed on this Monday and Tuesday. When I restarted the application manually in the morning after 9 am, it worked without issues.

Is there any maintenance going at night at Yodlee side recently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already a customer then please use Yodlee Customer Care tool for raising a Service Request else you can please fill out the form mentioned [**here**](http://solutions.yodlee.com/APIDeveloperInquiryForm.html) to provide the details like siteAccountId & REST URL you are using for us to debug further.

Yodlee do notify its clients beforehand, if there will be a maintenance activity scheduled.